# iPhone - MOV video with two audio channels

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a video that I want to use on an app that has localized versions. The video is the same but the audio changes. What I really want to do is to create a MOV with two audio channels and then select the audio channel language I would like to play, depending on the user language settings. Is it possible to do that on the iPhone/iPad?

OK, I know I can add two videos, but the videos are huge in size and I don't want to bloat the app.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is about the playback of the movie, not the creation of the movie, right?

Comment: yes, playback. ThomasW answer is what I want. Now I have to find a code that does that, so I can understand it in my specific case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [AVFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html) you can get the [`AVPlayerItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for the movie. Then you can access the `tracks` which are an array of [`AVPlayerItemTrack`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItemTrack_Class/Reference/Reference.html)s. These have an `enabled` property which you can set.

Now to determine which item to set you'll want to look at the `AVPlayerItemTrack`'s `assetTrack` property which is a [`AVAssetTrack`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetTrack_Class/Reference/Reference.html). This will probably hold the information for you to determine if it is the track you want to enable or not.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhh.....that's it. I will try to find a code for that, to understand it better. Thanks.